# How do I play 30 second games on chess.com?

Tags: online-chess, time-control

My current chess rating is approximately 1400 in 1 minute, 3 minute, and 5 minute games. I have seen some of the other players playing 30 seconds games whose rating is around 1200 but I cannot find an option to play 30 second games. How do I play 30 second games on chess.com?

Answer (score 7):

- Go into Live Chess.
- Click on the left button right above the "Play" button. It should currently display some time control.
- Click on the "More" button.
- Click on the "30 sec" button. For custom time controls, you can instead click on the "Custom" button and enter what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Desperate to play 30 sec bullet in the chess.com app?

Go to: More -> Watch -> Top games.

If you're lucky you'll find some 30 sec games going on. If found, just click on it and wait for the game to end. A widget will then pop up showing stuffs related to the match. It will also have the button "New 30 sec". Yes! Click on that!

Also, to play next time, you can always click on one of your previous 30 sec games (I need not say the next step..).